# parsing performance critical data in java

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, parsing

I have the following data in a file:

```
P1==1,P3==123d3213213345
P1==2,P2==123321512332456*
P1==3,P2==123321451232123332*,P4==9512*
P1==4,P3==312512343243234*,P4==98*, P5=453213264
```

I need to map it to the following structure which has one line of above data as input.

```
private static class ReferenceData {
    private int P1;
    private String P2;
    private String P3;
    private String P4;
    private String P5;
    public ReferenceData(String line) {
         //Parse and store in the corresponding class fields 
    }
}
```

This single structure is absolutely critical to the performance of my application.

What would be the fastest (And I mean a really fast way) to parse and store the above structure in their corresponding class fields?

I have done my homework. I have thoroughly profiled the code. This is exactly where the bottleneck is. Its not the IO or anything else.
Oh! and one more thing, the variables P1, P2 - they can be in thousands. This is just an example.

Note:
I can't use jni

Comment: What do the asterisks represent?

Comment: Also, why do you think the parsing is going to be the bottleneck... compared to disk or network IO, I mean...

Comment: Is P4 going to be there multiple times in the file? In that case which P4 value do you accept? Or is P1 the driver for each line?

Comment: Looks like doing a two simple splits on `,` then `==` should get you all the info you need to populate your object.

Comment: @rahul, are your files all csv files?

Comment: I think Dilum is right, the IO is probably going to be the bottleneck. If it isn't, I don't think that calling the regular expression engine is going to be a good idea when a simple state machine can suffice.

Comment: Is P1 always present, and is the value always a single digit? If so, you can extract the P1 value by a simple substring() call.

Comment: How fast can you do this already, and how fast do you need it to be?

Comment: No, its not the IO. I have profiled this code thoroughly. The bottleneck is the parsing. I have tried regex and splitting into tokens. I still have a bottleneck at the parsing.

Comment: @DNA. Yes that's true for the first variable. And yes that's how I did it. But its not the same for the other variables.

Comment: @mre, these are not csv files. The variables can come in any order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a hand-coded state machine parser and a simple benchmark test.  For the benchmark, I also included the other suggested parsing strategies:  split and regex (note that these didn't work as posted so I made some corrections).

Some notes:

- I used the sample data provided by the original poster, but removed the extra space and errant "d" character.  I think the "d" was a mistake.  Handling spaces could be added with a little more work if desired.
- Avoided allocations, such as the "new" operator or methods which would create objects.
- Avoided call to external methods -- at the cost of some code repetition.  (Note: there's still a case of Integer.parseInt() which could be done away with, avoiding an external call and also getting a more performant parse).

First the results:

```
Warming up...
Benchmarking...
average parse time for SplitParser: 5154.4ns
average parse time for RegexParser: 1820.8ns
average parse time for StateMachineParser: 401.3ns
```

And here's the code:

```
package test;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Parser {

  private static final List<String> SAMPLE_INPUTS = Arrays.asList(
    "P1==1,P3==1233213213345",
    "P1==2,P2==123321512332456*",
    "P1==3,P2==123321451232123332*,P4==9512*",
    "P1==4,P3==312512343243234*,P4==98*,P5==453213264");

  public static void main(String... args) {
    //test(new StateMachineParser());
    //test(new RegexParser());
    //test(new SplitParser());
    benchmark(Arrays.asList(new SplitParser(), new RegexParser(), new StateMachineParser()));
  }

  private static void test(ReferenceDataParser parser) {
    for (String input : SAMPLE_INPUTS) {
      try {
        System.err.println(parser.parse(input));
      }
      catch(ParseException pe) {
        System.err.println("Failed to parse: " + input);
        int offset = pe.getErrorOffset();
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder("                 ");
        for (int i = 0; i < offset; i++) {
          buf.append(' ');
        }
        buf.append('^');
        System.err.println(buf.toString());
        pe.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }


  private static void benchmark(List<ReferenceDataParser> parsers) {
    int warmupIters = 100 * 1000;
    int iters = 1000 * 1000;

    System.err.println("Warming up...");
    for (ReferenceDataParser parser : parsers) {
      try {
        for (String input : SAMPLE_INPUTS) {
          for (int i = 0; i < warmupIters; i++) {
            parser.parse(input);
          }
        }
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("parser failed: " + parser.getClass().getSimpleName());
      }
    }

    System.err.println("Benchmarking...");
    for (ReferenceDataParser parser : parsers) {
      try {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (String input : SAMPLE_INPUTS) {
          for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
            parser.parse(input);
          }
        }
        long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.err.println(String.format("average parse time for %s: %.1fns",
          parser.getClass().getSimpleName(), elapsed / (double) (iters * SAMPLE_INPUTS.size())));
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("parser failed: " + parser.getClass().getSimpleName());
      }
    }
  }

  public static interface ReferenceDataParser {

    public ReferenceData parse(String line) throws ParseException;

  }



  public static class ReferenceData {

    private final int p1;
    private final String p2;
    private final String p3;
    private final String p4;
    private final String p5;

    public ReferenceData(int p1, String p2, String p3, String p4, String p5) {
      this.p1 = p1;
      this.p2 = p2;
      this.p3 = p3;
      this.p4 = p4;
      this.p5 = p5;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return String.format("P1=%s,P2=%s,P3=%s,P4=%s,P5=%s", p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);
    }
  }


  private static class SplitParser implements ReferenceDataParser {

    public ReferenceData parse(String line) throws ParseException {
      int p1 = 0;
      String p2 = null;
      String p3 = null;
      String p4 = null;
      String p5 = null;

      String lineSplit[] = line.split(",");
      for(int i = 0; i < lineSplit.length; i++) {
        String value = lineSplit[i].split("==")[1];
        if(lineSplit[i].startsWith("P1")) {
          p1 = Integer.valueOf(value);
        }
        else if(lineSplit[i].startsWith("P2")) {
          p2 = value;
        }
        else if(lineSplit[i].startsWith("P3")) {
          p3 = value;
        }
        else if(lineSplit[i].startsWith("P4")) {
          p4 = value;
        }
        else if(lineSplit[i].startsWith("P5")) {
          p5 = value;
        }
      }

      return new ReferenceData(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);
    }

  }

  private static class RegexParser implements ReferenceDataParser {

    private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
      "(?:P1==(\\d+))(?:\\s*,P2==([0-9*]+))?(?:\\s*,P3==([0-9*]+))?(?:\\s*,P4==([0-9*]+))?(?:\\s*,P5==([0-9*]+))?");

    public ReferenceData parse(String line) throws ParseException {
      Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
      if(!m.matches()) {
        throw new ParseException(line, 0);
      }
      int p1 = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
      String p2 = m.group(2);//note: this can be null is P2 is not part of the line
      String p3 = m.group(3);
      String p4 = m.group(4);
      String p5 = m.group(5);
      return new ReferenceData(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);
    }

  }



  private static class StateMachineParser implements ReferenceDataParser {

    private static final int STATE_INITIAL_P = 0;
    private static final int STATE_P = 1;
    private static final int STATE_P_NUM = 2;
    private static final int STATE_EQ1 = 3;
    private static final int STATE_EQ2 = 4;
    private static final int STATE_VALUE = 5;

    public ReferenceData parse(String line) throws ParseException {
      int p1 = 0;
      String p2 = null;
      String p3 = null;
      String p4 = null;
      String p5 = null;

      int state = STATE_INITIAL_P;
      int length = line.length();
      int pNum = 0;
      int valueStart = 0;
      int valueEnd = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = line.charAt(i);
        switch(state) {
        case STATE_INITIAL_P:
        case STATE_P:
          if (c != 'P') {
            throw new ParseException(line, i);
          }
          state = STATE_P_NUM;
          break;
        case STATE_P_NUM:
          if (c < '1' || c > '5') {
            throw new ParseException(line, i);
          }
          pNum = c - '0';
          state = STATE_EQ1;
          break;
        case STATE_EQ1:
          if (c != '=') {
            throw new ParseException(line, i);
          }
          state = STATE_EQ2;
          break;
        case STATE_EQ2:
          if (c != '=') {
            throw new ParseException(line, i);
          }
          valueStart = valueEnd = i + 1;
          state = STATE_VALUE;
          break;
        case STATE_VALUE:
          if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || c == '*') {
            valueEnd++;
          }
          else if (c == ',') {
            if (valueStart == valueEnd) {
              throw new ParseException(line, i);
            }
            switch(pNum) {
            case 1:
              if (p1 != 0) {
                throw new ParseException(line, i);
              }
              p1 = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(valueStart, valueEnd));
              break;
            case 2:
              if (p2 != null) {
                throw new ParseException(line, i);
              }
              p2 = line.substring(valueStart, valueEnd);
              break;
            case 3:
              if (p3 != null) {
                throw new ParseException(line, i);
              }
              p3 = line.substring(valueStart, valueEnd);
              break;
            case 4:
              if (p4 != null) {
                throw new ParseException(line, i);
              }
              p4 = line.substring(valueStart, valueEnd);
              break;
            case 5:
              if (p5 != null) {
                throw new ParseException(line, i);
              }
              p5 = line.substring(valueStart, valueEnd);
              break;
            default:
              // illegal P-number
              throw new ParseException(line, i);
            }
            state = STATE_P;
          }
          break;
        }
      }
      switch(state) {
      case STATE_INITIAL_P:
      case STATE_P:
      case STATE_P_NUM:
      case STATE_EQ1:
      case STATE_EQ2:
        // invalid end-states
        throw new ParseException(line, length);
      case STATE_VALUE:
        // valid end-state; finish with last parsed value
        if (valueStart == valueEnd) {
          throw new ParseException(line, length);
        }
        switch(pNum) {
        case 1:
          if (p1 != 0) {
            throw new ParseException(line, length);
          }
          p1 = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(valueStart, valueEnd));
          break;
        case 2:
          if (p2 != null) {
            throw new ParseException(line, length);
          }
          p2 = line.substring(valueStart, valueEnd);
          break;
        case 3:
          if (p3 != null) {
            throw new ParseException(line, length);
          }
          p3 = line.substring(valueStart, valueEnd);
          break;
        case 4:
          if (p4 != null) {
            throw new ParseException(line, length);
          }
          p4 = line.substring(valueStart, valueEnd);
          break;
        case 5:
          if (p5 != null) {
            throw new ParseException(line, length);
          }
          p5 = line.substring(valueStart, valueEnd);
          break;
        default:
          // illegal P-number
          throw new ParseException(line, length);
        }
        break;
      default:
        throw new RuntimeException("unknown state: " + state);
      }
      return new ReferenceData(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);
    }

  }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

The absolute fastest way to do this is to write your own state machine based parser.

Comment: Sounds about right. Know any good material to learn how to write one?

Comment: @rahul you can check out how regexes are compiled and parsed this is done with state machines

Answer (score 1):

using a regex and assuming the Ps are always in order:

```
static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:P1=(\d*)),\s*(?:P2=(.*?))?,\s*(?:P3=(.*?))?,\s*(?:P4=(.*?))?,\s*(?:P5=(.*?))?");
public ReferenceData(String line) {
    Matcher m  = p.matcher(line);
    if(m.match()){
        P1 = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        P2 = m.group(2);//note: this can be null is P2 is not part of the line
        P3 = m.group(3);
        P4 = m.group(4);
        P5 = m.group(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using regex is much slower than just splitting it into tokens. Understand that I already know how to parse it. What I need is the fastest way to do so.

Comment: did you profile it? a lot of the slowness of regex comes from backtracking in most implementations

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the speed of this, but you should be able to use some simple splits to do what you need, assuming the file can't be malformed and you don't have to check for bad lines:

```
public ReferenceData(String line) {
  String lineSplit[] = line.split(",");
  for(int i = 0; i < lineSplit.length; i++) {
    String value = lineSplit[i].split("==")[1];
    if(lineSplit[i].equals("P1")) {
      this.P1 = Integer.valueOf(value);
    }
    else if(lineSplit[i].equals("P2")) {
      this.P2 = value;
    }
    else if(lineSplit[i].equals("P3")) {
      this.P3 = value;
    }
    else if(lineSplit[i].equals("P4")) {
      this.P4 = value;
    }
    else if(lineSplit[i].equals("P5")) {
      this.P5 = value;
    }
  }
}
```